# A Condition for division ring being a field.

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, finite-fields, division-algebras

I'm reading a paper of Maurice Chacron and I.N. Herstein entitled [Powers of skew  and symmetric elements in division rings](https://www.math.uh.edu/~hjm/v001n1/0015CHACRON.pdf).
At the first page of the paper, I got stuck in a problem that:

> "if in a division ring $R$, $a^{m}b^{n}=b^{n}a^{m}$, for all $a, b \in R$, and appropriate $m,n >0$ depending on $a,b$, then $R$ is a field".

Is this a right statement? Thanks for helping me!

Comment: IOW, $\forall a,b\in R ~\exists m,n>0~a^mb^n=b^na^m$

Comment: Do you think that statement is right? @arctictern

Comment: A commutative division ring is a field, so it's true if you always take $m=n=1$.  Is there some context in that paper for the appearance of $m, n$?

Comment: @Kimball What do you mean by "take" $m=n=1$? While such $m$ and $n$ exist, they may depend on $a,b$.

Comment: @arctictern It seems I interpreted the word "appropriate" in the quote differently than you did.  I thought there was some context for it so the quote meant something different from your comment without words.  But probably your interpretation is the intended one.